# Does "Increases experience awarded by +x%" affect party members?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm paired with a friend who has a ruby in his helm (+19% experience rewarded).  We seem to be leveling at roughly the same rate.  Is the 19% shared between us?  (Are we both getting +9.5%?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything such as magic find, gold find, and extra experience gets shared across the party.

*E.g.* 40 combined extra exp with 4 members, means 10 exp extra each.

Comment: So theoretically, it will be better to solo with a +19% exp than to do it with a party?

Comment: Yes, if you look only at sharing; and not other factors like "who will resurrect me when I die".